# communicating with a memory mapped device in linux

Tags: c, linux

I have a memory mapped device and I need to communicate with it. My boss told me that it is possible to it through `/dev/mem`. I looked online and didn't find anything related to it. Is it possible to do it or my boss was wrong?

Assume that you have superuser permissions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You got a memory mapped device at address `MMIO_ADDR` which occupies `MMIO_LEN` of bytes. You need to toggle the 123rd byte in the device's address space. This could look like this:

```
#define MMIO_ADDR 0xDEAD0000
#define MMIO_LEN  0x400

// open a handle into physical memory, requires root
int memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
// map the range [MMIO_ADDR, MMIO_ADDR+MMIO_LEN] into your virtual address space
unsigned char* shmem = mmap(0, MMIO_LEN, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, memfd, MMIO_ADDR);

// do your deed
unsigned char *magic_toggle_byte = &shmem[123];
*magic_toggle_byte = !*magic_toggle_byte;
```

Comment: I asked more questions online and it looks like that for `mmap` to work a device needs a driver. At the moment there isn't one. I need something very simple until a driver is developed. Is it possible to communicate with a device by reading and writing to `/dev/mem` directly?

Comment: @flashburn: You need a driver regardless.  By opening /dev/mem you are using the generic /dev/mem driver which can access anything that is memory mapped.  Using the /dev/mem driver, you can use read, write or mmap to access the memory mapped device.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I've never done this kind of "stuff" before. How do I find out how my device is mapped?

Comment: @a3f This is a PCI device. As far as I understand PCI devices have BAR registers. If I'm to talk to this device, would the values in BAR registers correspond to `MMIO_ADDR`?

Comment: @a3f Say I want to read multiple bytes at once. Will using `memcpy` work instead of `unsigned char *magic_toggle_byte = &shmem[123];`?

Comment: @flasburn Check out [pcimem](https://github.com/billfarrow/pcimem) for a command line tool to poke with PCI registers. You should map the device's resource in sysfs as pcimem does, not `/dev/mem`. Using `memcpy` [seems to be ok](https://github.com/billfarrow/pcimem).

Answer (score 1):

The device node `/dev/mem` gives you direct access to the system's *physical* memory.

You can find device memory mappings in `/proc/iomem`. Note that there is also `/dev/ports` and its counterpart `/proc/ioports`. Through the files in `/proc` you would determine at which position in `/dev/mem` your device's memory is mapped.

It is certainly possible to use `/dev/mem` for accessing mapped regions (often, access is explicitely restricted to memory-mapped regions) using regular file operations. I cannot tell you if it is the best way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

The file `/dev/mem` has a [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html).  It sounds like you just open `/dev/mem` and do regular file operations to read and write from memory.  You would probably use the `open` system call to open it, `lseek` to go to a particular address, and `read` or `write` to access the memory at that address.

It looks like the kernel source code that powers `/dev/mem` is here:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/mem.c