# communicating with a PCI device through /dev/mem

Tags: c, pci, memory-mapping

I'm need to communicate with a memory PCI device through `/dev/mem`. Why? There are many reasons, one of which is because my boss told me so.

I think I have my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317873/1636521). What I can't figure out however is the `MMIO_ADDR` in the answer. If I want to communicate with a specific memory region, would I use a value stored in a `BAR` register as my `MMIO_ADDR`? If no then how do I communicate with my PCI device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BAR will have been assigned an address by the BIOS/kernel. That address should have been written into the BAR address registers in the PCI configuration header by the time the system is up.

For example, on a VM I have here, the e1000 device is as follows (from `lspci -v`):

```
02:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
        Subsystem: VMware PRO/1000 MT Single Port Adapter
        Physical Slot: 35
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
   =>   Memory at fd560000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Memory at fdfd0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        I/O ports at 2080 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at fd520000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: e1000
```

You'll need to read that info (you can reach it in binary form via `/proc/bus/pci/<Bus>/<DevFn>` or via `/sys/bus/pci/devices/`) to find the MMIO address.

For example, dumping the binary of the PCI configuration space for the device above shows:

```
od -tx1z -Ax /proc/bus/pci/02/03.0
000000 86 80 0f 10 17 01 30 02 01 00 00 02 10 00 00 00  >......0.........<
000010 04 00 56 fd 00 00 00 00 04 00 fd fd 00 00 00 00  >..V.............<
000020 81 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ad 15 50 07  >. ............P.<
000030 00 00 00 00 dc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 ff 00  >................<
000040
```

The first BAR (bar region #0) is at offset 0x10, the second (bar region #2) is at offset 0x18.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space for description of the layout and interpretation.

Comment: I have a way to extract BAR values. But my question still stands, are BAR values the ones I need to use for `MMIO_ADDR`?

Comment: I think there is an error in your response. The second bar should be at 0x14

Comment: Well, the second one shown by `lspci`. I'll clarify

Comment: BTW, if you run `lspci -vvv`, it shows exactly which BAR is which.

Comment: Yes, the BAR memory address base is the one you need to use for your mmap call. The amount of memory you need to mmap varies. You may not need to map the entire BAR region. In fact, you might only need to map one page. It depends on what use is being made of the region by the particular device.

Comment: What did you mean by that I don't need to map entire BAR region? If I need to read/write to entire BAR region, does it mean I need to map all of it? As far as I understand that's what I need to do.